# What is the term for someone who requests a copy of a document?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I would like to know if there is an accepted English noun or short phrase for the person who asks for a copy of an official document. In this case, I'm dealing with the translation of an academic transcript from Spanish, where this person is referred to as the *interesado*, i.e. the interested party. He or she is supposed to be one of the parents of the former student. Though “interested party” seems correct, maybe I'm missing some other, more specific word. I've seen “requester” suggested in a different question, but I don't think I've ever seen that word before. Synonyms for it found in thesauri, like “applicant” and “petitioner”, don't really fit the concept.

Comment: Requestor is right, but vague. Interested party suggests the right to view the document, but not the request for it.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific word for this. I doubt that "interesado" is that specific, either. It's just the context that makes it clear that they're the requestor. The same will be true in English.

Comment: Be aware that the OED attests only the spelling *requester*, not the *-or* spelling.  Sometimes the suffix choice for agent nouns can be difficult to predict, and both versions can often be found in the historical record. They further note that *In received spelling, the choice between the two forms is often capricious, or determined by other than historical reasons.*

Comment: In some contexts you might use "supplicant".

Comment: *Customer* if they're paying for it.

Comment: Following up on Barmar's comment, it is unclear whether you are seeking **(1)** a term that **means** 'someone who requests a copy of a document', or **(2)** a term that could be used for such a person, even though its meaning may be much wider. The title of the question leaves an impression that it is (1), but your references to *interesado* in the body of the question imply (2). It also needs to be explained why '“applicant” and “petitioner”, don't really fit the concept'.

Comment: @jsw29 I've accepted the suggestion of "applicant". I assumed it did not match the idea because I've only ever seen the word in contexts where it refers to applications for jobs, grants, etc., and not for requests of things that actually belong to the petitioner already (e.g. his or her own school grades).

Comment: @pablodf76, you are right that in such cases, where the matter is very straightforward, *applicant* may not be the right word, but then in such cases there is usually no need for a special term for the person as a seeker of the document; the person is likely to be referred to according to whatever status the person generally has with respect to the institution (in your example, as a student).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you're likely to get is "applicant".

https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/36/section/8 tells us how the Freedom of Information Act 2000 describes one who requests official documents as "the applicant".

It says:
(1)In this Act any reference to a “request for information” is a reference to such a request which—
(a)is in writing,
(b)states the name of the applicant (and stuff)

Other than the fact that "applicant" also has other uses, how does it not fit the concept, please?

Common English usage simply doesn't bother with such detail, in the same way that while "inquisitor" or "interrogator" might be correct, few natives would opt for anything but "question master."

Answer (score 1):

Spanish has *el interesado*, French has *l'intéressé*, most dictionaries translate this into English as *the person concerned*

- [español-inglés](https://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/firmado+por+el+interesado.html)
- [français-anglais](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=requ%C3%AAte+de+l%27int%C3%A9ress%C3%A9)